# AppEngine local dev server for Google Cloud Endpoints Framework V2 not work

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints

I can't get running Google Endpoints Framework V2 on local AppEngine development server.

To demonstrate an issue i created a gradle [demo project](https://github.com/softkot/framework-v2-someapi)
It works just fine if deploy to real AppEngine standard environment instance but does not work with local dev server.

The steps to reproduce:

1. edit appengine-web.xml in case wish to change default appengine service name (framework-v2-someapi) and change that name on step 5 as well.
2. gcloud auth login
3. gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
4. ./gradlew appengineDeploy
5. gcloud app browse -s framework-v2-someapi
6. Click API link in new opened browser window.
7. Play with API Explorer and check the Services > someapi API v1 > someapi.method.getHash works fine.
8. ./gradlew appengineStart and open http://localhost:8080 to try do the same localy and get errors instead.

Eventually got

> Jan 24, 2017 7:25:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.devappserver2.RemoteApiDelegate log
>   SEVERE: [1485285940023000] javax.servlet.ServletContext log:
>   unavailable com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiException:
>   response was a   python exception:
>   cgoogle.appengine.runtime.apiproxy_errors ApplicationError

My question is how to run Google Endpoints Framework V2 localy?

Comment: Hi, there's currently a bug (fix in review) in the API management code that will be fixed in 1.0.1 of the endpoints-management-control-appengine artifact. Apologies for the inconvenience. If you don't need metrics right now, I would comment out the GoogleAppEngineControlFilter in `web.xml`.

Comment: Thanks saiyr , but if you take a look on a code, there is no GoogleAppEngineControlFilter  at https://github.com/softkot/framework-v2-someapi/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: It's in a different library. Can you update your sample repository and try again?

Comment: Saiyr, could you be a little more specific? What do I need to update?

Comment: @saiyr Meantime try to follow [Quickstart for Cloud Endpoints Frameworks on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/quickstart-frameworks-java) and get the same behaviour. Project buil and deploy just fine but running the sample locally mvn appengine:run ends up with

`[INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: failed endpoints-api-controller: com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiException: response was a python exception:
[INFO] GCLOUD: cgoogle.appengine.runtime.apiproxy_errors
[INFO] GCLOUD: ApplicationError`

Answer (score 1):

The solution found by the original poster was to set the `<version>` tag inside his appengine-web.xml file. A description of this tag can be found on the `README` of this Github helloworld java-docs-samples [repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/helloworld).

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle`, change

```
compile 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-management-control-appengine:1.0.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-management-control-appengine:1.0.1'
```

Comment: No, it doesn't resolve an issue. It is reprodicable with [Quickstart for Cloud Endpoints Frameworks on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/quickstart-frameworks-java) as well and got the same errors.

Comment: Eventually i found that dev_appserver.py are different in google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java and appengin-java-sdk latest bundles. Gcloud version requires  deprecated <version> tag inside appengine-web.xml in order to run endpoints.

Comment: Are you saying it works after adding the version? Endpoints Frameworks aren't fully supported on Flex yet.

Comment: The first,  i am talking about running under dev_appserver.py only. I am using standart renvironment only. And yes dev_appserver.py with endpoints code starts to work if include version tag.